# PHP and MySQL query output different

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following query.  When I run the query straight in MySQL I get all the information but when I run the same query in my PHP script it's missing some information.  I ran the query in MySQL first to make sure that I I get everything I need and then copied the query into my php script.  Can anyone please help:

```
$get_attendance_profile_stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT
p_info.fname AS \'First name\',
p_info.lname AS \'Lastname\',
stud_info.t_belt_id,
t_b.short_descr,
t_b.long_descr, 
stud_info.h_belt_id,
h_b.short_descr,
h_b.long_descr,

AB.*,
ROUND(
    (
        AB.Considered_Attended / AB.Classes_Tought * 100
    ),
    0
) AS \'Attendance %\'
FROM
(
SELECT
    student_id,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN attendance_reason = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS \'Sick\',
    SUM(
    CASE WHEN attendance_reason = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS \'Injured\',
    SUM(
    CASE WHEN attendance_reason = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS \'Work\',
    SUM(
    CASE WHEN attendance_reason = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS \'School\',
    SUM(
    CASE WHEN attendance_reason = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS \'Did not attend\',
    SUM(
    CASE WHEN attendance_reason = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS \'Present\',
    SUM(
    CASE WHEN attendance_reason != 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
    ) AS \'Considered_Attended\',
    MAX(DateCounter) AS \'Classes_Tought\'
    FROM
    attendance a
    JOIN(
    SELECT COUNT(
        DISTINCT CONVERT(creation_date, DATE)
    ) AS DateCounter
    FROM
    attendance
    WHERE
    creation_date <= (SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))
    ) DT
    WHERE
    creation_date <= (SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
    GROUP BY
    student_id
    ) AB
    JOIN student_info stud_info ON
    stud_info.student_id = AB.student_id
    JOIN users u ON
    stud_info.uid = u.uid
    JOIN personal_info p_info ON
    u.uid = p_info.uid
    LEFT JOIN t_belts t_b ON 
    stud_info.t_belt_id = t_b.t_belt_id
    LEFT JOIN h_belts h_b ON
    stud_info.h_belt_id = h_b.h_belt_id
    WHERE
    u.account_status = \'Active\'');
```

My output running the query inside MySQL is like this:
[image]

The output of the query in php looks like this:
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that the two missing fields are from a table named `t_b` in your query. Can you verify that those fields actually exist in that table?

Comment: You know, if your string contains a whole bunch of single quotes and no double quotes, you can just quote the string with double quotes and that way you don't have to escape every single single quote within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP array's need to have unique indices. Your query returns 2 columns with the same name so the second values are what you get (they overwrite the first during assignment, simple example https://3v4l.org/sbs41 )). As can be seen in the screenshot your second columns are empty. Use an alias on the first columns (or the second) so your indices in PHP are unique. e.g.

```
SELECT
p_info.fname AS \'First name\',
p_info.lname AS \'Lastname\',
stud_info.t_belt_id,
t_b.short_descr,
t_b.long_descr, 
stud_info.h_belt_id,
h_b.short_descr as short_descr_dontcare,
h_b.long_descr as long_descr_dontcare
```

or

```
SELECT
p_info.fname AS \'First name\',
p_info.lname AS \'Lastname\',
stud_info.t_belt_id,
t_b.short_descr  as short_descr_real,
t_b.long_descr as long_descr_real, 
stud_info.h_belt_id,
h_b.short_descr,
h_b.long_descr
```

with the latter approach you'll need to modify the indices in your PHP array with `_real`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that alias fixed it :)